# One vs He/She vs We

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

What is more preferable way to say about person in general without definite gender? Is it `one`, `he/she` or `we`? I would not thought about that unless had not read `Martin Eden` by Jack London. There was a moment when Ruth Morse the embodiment of education in the plot of the book said to Martin that it is really uneducated to say `he/she` and `we`.

For example what is the best choice out of these three:

> Let us suppose `one` has the task.

> Let us suppose `he/she` has the task.

> Let us suppose `we` have the task.

?

[Usage of "they" / "them" / "their" when the person's gender is not known](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/usage-of-they-them-their-in-place-of-he-him-his-or-she)
There is no `we and one` problem in the question.

**UPDATE**

I am not sure how can someone be so blind to not being able to see the difference between the `One, He, She, We` and the `They, Them, Their`. That are completely different words. My question is about the former, not latter. So, I can not understand why my question is marked as a duplicate about the latter. Unless an explanation is provided, I will consider it as an act of fraud. From my point of view the act is to get me stop using the StackExchange by bullying me. I am very confused that moderators allow such things here.

Comment: Please see this link.  "Uneducated", no, but certainly confusing.  There are many ways to avoid using gendered pronouns but they often require a little art to not sound clumsy.

Comment: Note that ***I / you / we / one*** could reasonably start a discourse using any of those pronouns to refer to *a person in general*, but this is not possible with ***he / she*** - where the person (or *type of person*) must have already been referenced.

Comment: @Andrew, what link are you referencing? I see no links in you comment.