# What use when I don't know the gender of a person?

Tags: pronouns, singular-they, gender

When I don't know if a person is male or female, what word shall I use? I don't know but in spanish we use the male form: he.
**PD:** I know that I could say He/She but I don't want.

Comment: See [use of singular *they*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their) on our sister site, English Language & Usage.

Comment: @Robusto Thanks! That answer my question perfect. Shall I delete my post?

Comment: Related : https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/62371/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61524/discussion-between-colleenv-and-catija).