# Can we use singular pronoun for referring to "everyone"?

Tags: singular, singular-they

If both sentences are true, how can we justify them? Can we use singular pronoun for referring to "everyone"?

> 1. I bet everyone regardless of genders can find at least one item [they love].
> 2. I bet everyone regardless of genders can find at least one item [he/she loves].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of "they" / "them" / "their" when the person's gender is not known](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/usage-of-they-them-their-when-the-persons-gender-is-not-known)

Comment: *I bet **everyone** regardless of gender can find at least one item to love*.

Comment: I appreciate your participation, but I wonder if these two sentences are grammatically correct? and if they are, how can we justify using singular pronoun for referring to  subject "everyone"?

Comment: Oof.  So topical with regard to the site.   But, duplicate question.